# How to get link URL from JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have the following code :

```
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach($this->list as $l) { 
$link = JRoute::_("index.php?option=com_ecommerce&view=detail&id=$l->id");
<div class="quickview" id="quickview_<?php echo $i;?>">
<a href='<?php echo $link ?>' class='basic'>Quick view</a>
</div>
i++;
}
?>
<script>
jQuery(function ($){
    var link = $('.quickview .basic').val();
    $('.quickview .basic').click(function (e) {
    alert(link);
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

I can't get link from tag `<a>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var link =$('.quickview .basic').attr("href");`  should do the trick.

Comment: I think prop() should be used in this case

Comment: I think both are valid no? IMHO, in this case "href" is both an attr (of the html tag) and a prop (of the DOM object)

Answer (score 0):

If you refer

> I can't get link from tag <a>, please help me!

to the link you're clicking, this would work:

```
$(".quickview").find(".basic").click(function(e) {

     e.preventDefault();
     var url = $(this).attr("href");
     alert(url);
});
```